# how to update data of an array inside a map in flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

I want to Update a array inside a map

```
Map<int, List<String>> testtable = {
    1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e'],
    2: ['f', 'g', 'h', 'j'],
  };
```

I want to Update e => d in array which has key = 1 ,

I Have Tried this `testtable.update(1, (list[3]) => d);` but doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update` expect the new value as the parameter, so you have to return the whole list.

```
testtable.update(1, (list) {
    list[3] = 'd';
    return list;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```dart
testtable.update(
  1,
  (value) {
    value[3] = 'd';
    return value;
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
void main() {
  Map<int, List<String>> testtable = {
    1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e'],
    2: ['f', 'g', 'h', 'j'],
  };
  
  print (testtable);
  
  testtable[1][3]='d';
  print (testtable);
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work,, it only works with List<List<String>> ,not map

Comment: Why shouldn't it work? It is valid and works. One way to read values from a Map is uisng the `[]` operator. In this example your Map's keys are integers so `testtable[1]` is totally correct and returns the value of key 1.

Comment: I tested it in dartpad before posting, and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Update nested Map

```dart
 Map<String, Map> selectedTimes = {
    "monday": {"open": "7:30 AM", "close": "10:30 AM"},
    "tuesday": {"open": "7:30 AM", "close": "10:30 AM"},
    "wednesday": {"open": "7:30 AM", "close": "10:30 AM"},
    "thursday": {"open": "7:30 AM", "close": "10:30 AM"},
    "friday": {"open": "7:30 AM", "close": "10:30 AM"},
    "saturday": {"open": "7:30 AM", "close": "10:30 AM"},
    "sunday": {"open": "7:30 AM", "close": "10:30 AM"}
  };


selectedTimes.update(day, (list) {
  list.update(
      time, (value) => selectedTimeRTL!.format(context).toString());
  return list;
})
```